# What algorithms solve the minimun multidimensional multidemand 0-1 knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

I've found an heuristic algorithm[scatter search] that solves the common version of MDMKP(MultiDemand Multidimensional Knapsack Problem)[the one that maximizes] but what about the minimize version? is there any algorithm for that kind of problem? is it possible to obtain the solution to the minimum MDMKP from the maximum MDMKP?
Here's the maximum MDMKP formally expressed:
[image: MDMKP]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Also, what have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  Have you tried working through an example or two?

Answer (score 0):

Negate the coefficients (the $c_j$'s) and adjusting the other coefficients correspondingly.

In particular, replace $c_j$ with $-c_j$.  Note that $\sum -c_j x_j$ is maximized whenever $\sum c_j x_j$ is minimized.   Then, you can apply a change of variables to get the new linear inequalities (try $x_j=1-y_j$).